# Zip files not highlighted issue in Enterprise Search site

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, search-results, enterprise-search

I have enabled  enterprise search in my SharePoint 2013 farm. The search service crawls a publishing site collection that is one of my Web Applications. A few users have uploaded some zip files into the publishing site.

I have observed that, in zip files/compressed files, the searched keyword is not mentioned or highlighted. In order to avoid the situation can the zip files be restricted in Search results? Can I hide the zip files from crawling?

Answer (score 3):

You can prevent the files from being crawled. They won't show up in search results at all. Just create a crawl rule that Excludes the path to the zip files `https://yoursite/*.zip`